# ReactJS MUI Select Component: Get pre-select value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there a native MUI event for when the pre-selection value changes in a MUI:Select component?

For example, here is my MUI:Select component with 3 options:

[image: Example]

I would like an event for when 'Public', 'Restricted' or 'Private' is pre-selected (but not actually selected; i.e. before the `onChange()` event), either with a mouse-over event or a keyboard up/down event. This is because I have a tooltip card that needs to change dynamically for the user as they interact with the options.

Using this example https://codesandbox.io/s/3iv96 as a guide, I implemented a bespoke solution by capturing the mouse-over event and extracting the text value. I just realized I have forgotten to handle key up/down.

So the question becomes whether I have just missed the obvious, or do I need to roll my own component by wrapping MUI:Select and publishing the events I need.

Comment: Can you share your code or codesandbox so someone can look into it and help you.

Comment: Updated question with a link to a sandbox that has helped me thus far.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like out of the box this isn't supported.

Looking at this thread https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/745 it has to be done manually.